# How does Pym particle density work?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015, ant-man-and-the-wasp

I recently saw the Ant-Man films, and the logician in me has some questions, specifically about the way the Pym particles affect density. In the first film, Hope tells Scott how the Pym particles, because of how they shrink, increase the density of the object they are shrinking. This means that Scott, while the size of an ant, has the strength of a 200lb man. But if this is so, shouldn't he have the weight of a 200lb man? He clearly doesn't, since he is able to sit on Louise's shoulder without Louise noticing.

As well as this, when Scott is Giant-Man, his strength goes up too. This is demonstrated in the scene in Ant-Man and the Wasp where Giant-man picks up an unconscious Hope from the quantum tunnel with one hand. How can this be? Surely if little Scott's strength remains the same as normal-size Scott, then big Scott's strength should do the same?